# undefined local variable or method `toggle_follow_path'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I'm getting this error `undefined local variable or method`toggle_follow_path'` in the view folder .I probably got something wrong with the method or the use off form_tag + toggle_follow_path any help would be welcome thank you . by the way the goal of the toggle follow is to follow or un follow some one.

**in the route file**

```
 match '/:username/toggle_follow',       to: 'home#toggle_follow'
```

**home controller**

```
def toggle_follow
     @user =  User.find_by_username(params[:username])
     if current_user.is_friend? @user
       flash[:notice] = "You are no longer following @#{@user.username}"
       current_user.remove_friend(@user)
     else
       flash[:notice] = "You are now following @#{@user.username}"
       current_user.add_friend(@user)
     end
     redirect_to user_flits_path(@user)

  end
```

**view**

```
<h1><%= image_tag @user.gravatar_url, :align => "top" %> <%= @user.username %></h1>

<%= form_tag  toggle_follow_path, :method => :post do  %>
  <% if current_user.is_friend? @user %>
     <%=h submit_tag "Following"  , :class => "button" %>
  <% else %>
     <%=h submit_tag "Follow"  , :class => "button" %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
<%=h render :partial => "flits_list", :locals => {:flits => @flits }%>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `:as` option for `match` to specify the desired helper's name:

```
match '/:username/toggle_follow', to: 'home#toggle_follow', as: 'toggle_follow'
```

This way both `toggle_follow_path` and `toggle_follow_url` will be created.

Answer (score 0):

It needs to take in a `:username` param.

Try this:

```
toggle_follow_path(:username => "johndoe") # fill in the correct username.
```

Comment: but by using @user find by username in  the controller doesn't the mean that i dont have to specify it on the path it's question by the way